# C++ priority queue constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue

I found the constructor of priority_queue on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/ is like this :

```
priority_queue (const Compare& comp, const Container& ctnr);
```

but the example I found is like this:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q2;
```

What's the difference between these two constructors?

I have tried both of them on my own, but the first one didn't work, the priority_queue wasn't sorted from small to large. Here is the code:

```
priority_queue<greater<int>, vector<int>> pq;
pq.push(4);
pq.push(2);
pq.push(1);
pq.push(3);
pq.push(5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << pq.top() << endl;
    pq.pop();  
}
```

The result is still 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: You seem to be confused regarding the difference betwen a constructor, and a declaration.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you got me wrong, my point is the first one takes two parameters and the second one takes three. I need to edit my question a little bit, it is confusing.

Comment: Second one actually takes zero parameters. Check [better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) and try to understand difference between templated variable declaration, and constructor.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between these two constructors?

One of them is a constructor; the other is not.

The line beginning `typedef` just creates a type alias, called `mypq_type`. You would still pass those same constructor arguments when you create an object of this `mypq_type` type.

Comment: Sorry, my original question was rather confusing, I've touched it up for clarification.

Comment: @myyukiho: You're still comparing a constructor to something that is not a constructor.